# Non-nesting matchings and Catalan numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, catalan-numbers

It is well-known that the number of non-nesting perfect matchings on $2n$ points is given by the Catalan number $C_n$; see part (a) of the figure below. This is item e^5 in Stanley's list ([http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/catadd.pdf](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/ec/catadd.pdf)).

[The following section has been edited to account for an initial mistake in the description.]
Now I am interested in non-nesting arc diagrams on $n+1$ points, where no arc connects two neighboring points (two arcs may meet in the same point, one arc from above and one arc from below, so the arcs may not form a matching); see part (b) of the figure below. These diagrams are also counted by $C_n$, and it is easy to prove this.

This must be a known fact, but the second type of arc diagrams is not in Stanley's book (maybe I overlooked it), so who has references for this type of arc diagrams with regards to Catalan numbers?

[image]

Comment: I only find 12 non-nesting matchings of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ without arcs connecting neighbouring points.  Did I misunderstand your definition?

Comment: (this would be https://oeis.org/A089372, Motzkin paths without peaks on level 1)

Comment: I get the same count as Martin Rubey, my list is $(\ )$, $(13)$, $(14)$, $(15)$, $(24)$, $(25)$, $(35)$, $(13, 24)$, $(13, 25)$, $(14, 25)$, $(14, 35)$, $(24, 35)$. What are the two that I am missing?

Comment: Thanks to Martin and David for pointing out a mistake in my description. I really meant arc diagrams and not matchings (description above is now corrected), i.e., it may happen that two arcs meet in the same point. This gives the two missing diagrams for $n=4$, namely $(13,24,35)$ and $(13,35)$, which are the last two diagrams in the picture I added above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are nonnesting partitions, which are usually defined as anti-chains in the root poset. Namely, the root poset (in $S_n$) is $\{ e_j-e_i : 1 \leq i < j \leq n \}$ with $e_k - e_j \leq e_{\ell} - e_i$ if $i \leq j < k \leq \ell$. Your arc diagrams turn into nonnesting partitions by $(i,j+1) \mapsto e_j-e_i$.

Googling "nonnesting partition" will give you a ton of hits.